# AFNetworking 2 and background tasks

Tags: ios, background-process, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I have a question about AFNetworking 2 and background downloads/uploads thanks to the new iOS7 NSURLSession background requests

Is this automatically handled by my `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` ? Does it automatically set my requests'session to background mode?
I saw that the `AFURLSessionManager` Has a `setDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSessionBlock` Method but I wonder if everything is automatic?

If my app is killed or suspended, will requests keep on going? How can I get a callback when my app is relaunched?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` uses the old `NSURLConnection` so that doesn't facilitate background downloading.

`AFURLSessionManager` uses `NSURLSession` under the hood so that does. I think you still need to configure the `NSURLSession` appropriately.

"The NSURLSession class supports background transfers while your app is suspended. Background transfers are provided only by sessions created using a background session configuration object (as returned by a call to backgroundSessionConfiguration:)."

Suggested reading:[URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)